# How do I "convert" System.out.println into variable.getText(); android

Tags: java, android

I have written a Java program which I want to make into an android application,

I have a class called TowersOfHanoi in the java program where output is done this way:

System.out.println("Move disk " + n + " from " + start + " to " + end);

and I have a mainActivity file where I am calling TowersOfHanoi from however I dont know how to change it from system.ouut... to variable.getText.TowersOfHanoi etc and make it work.

```
MainActivity code: 
       package com.example.towersofhanoiapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private TowersOfHanoi towersOfHanoi;
    private Button submit;
    static TextView display; 
    private EditText discs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        towersOfHanoi = new TowersOfHanoi(); 
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
        discs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String discsString= discs.getText().toString();
                if (!discsString.isEmpty()){
                    int discsInt =Integer.parseInt(discsString);
                    TowersOfHanoi.solve(discsInt,"Peg A", "Peg B", "Peg C");

                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

TowerOfHanoi Method

```
    package com.example.towersofhanoiapp;

public class TowersOfHanoi {

   public static void solve(int n, String start, String auxiliary, String end) {
       if (n == 1) {
           System.out.println("Move disk "+ n + " from " + start + " to " + end);
       } else {
           solve(n - 1, start, end, auxiliary);
           System.out.println("Move disk " + n + " from " + start + " to " + end);
           solve(n - 1, auxiliary, start, end);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: TextView.setText()  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setText()` on `discs`, and convert your method `solve` to return `String` instead of doing println.

The easiest would be to create a `StringBuilder` at the beginning of the method and then replace `System.out.println` with `builder.append`.
At the end of the method you have to add `return builder.toString()` and result of this method you should use in the `setText`.

```
public static void solve(...) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   if (...) {
       ....
    } else {
       ....
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.towersofhanoiapp;

public class TowersOfHanoi {

   public static String solve(int n, String start, String auxiliary, String end) {
       if (n == 1) {
            return "Move disk "+ n + " from " + start + " to " + end);
       } else {
           solve(n - 1, start, end, auxiliary);
           return ("Move disk " + n + " from " + start + " to " + end);
           solve(n - 1, auxiliary, start, end);
       }
   }
```

and in your click

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String discsString= discs.getText().toString();
        if (!discsString.isEmpty()){
            int discsInt =Integer.parseInt(discsString);
            display.setText(TowersOfHanoi.solve(discsInt,"Peg A", "Peg B", "Peg C"));

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could to do in this case (and only if you want to keep those System.out calls) is to make System.out print to another PrintStream. You can do something like this:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream testSystemOut(){
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final PrintStream printStream = new     PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        System.setOut(printStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
public static final String THIS_IS_THE_SENTENCE_YOU_ARE_EXPECTING = "This is the sentence you are expecting!";

@Test
public void testSystemOut() throws Exception {

    final SystemOut systemOut = new SystemOut();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream printer = systemOut.testSystemOut();

    System.out.print(THIS_IS_THE_SENTENCE_YOU_ARE_EXPECTING);

    assertThat(printer.toString(), equalTo(THIS_IS_THE_SENTENCE_YOU_ARE_EXPECTING));
}
```

This solution is only a workaround if you want to keep using System.out. Be aware that if you do this, all System.out calls will not print to the console anymore. They will now print only to the output stream, unless you do some sort of management by keeping the a reference to the old PrintStream and switch on/off when needed.